# How to see all nics in Solaris 8/9

Tags: networking, hardware, nic, solaris

I have a questions regarding how to see all NICS in the solaris 8/9 SPARC boxes.
Even if they are active/inactive.

`dladm show-link` command does not work.
cat /etc/path_to_inst could but it's hard to make out the NICS.

Also when a cable is disconnected from the NIC ifconfig -a still shows the NIC as "UP/RUNNING"
without looking at the system message, is there a way to know that the NIC is unplugged?

Thank you!

Comment: How does the dladm command not work ?

Comment: This is Solaris 8/9. I think dladm was only added after solaris 10.
I do not think that there is a patch for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display all plumbed interfaces, run

```
# ifconfig -a
```

If you want to see the unplumbed ones, a simple way would be to plumb them first:

```
# ifconfig -a plumb 2>/dev/null
# ifconfig -a
```

To know if an interface is plugged or not, this command should work:

```
# ndd /dev/bge0 link_status
```